# Total number of divisors of $2015^8$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

How many total number of divisors of $2015^8$ are there ?

---

How to approach for such problems ?

Comment: Use the formula for the number of divisors. If n=p1^a1 p2^a2 ... pk^ak (the prime factorization of n), then the number of divisors is given by (a1+1)(a2+1)...(an+1)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I made a typo. It is actually $2015^8$. I have corrected now !!

Comment: In general, I think this type of question ask in natural number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is actually a rule for these types of problems.

First, factor $2015^8$ into $5^8$ $*$ $13^8$ $*$ $31^8$.

Then, take the exponents of each prime factor and add one to each of them and multiply them out.

You have $9$ $*$ $9$ $*$ $9$ = $729$ factors of $2015^8$.

This works for any number.

Comment: It should be mentioned that this counts only the *positive* divisors.  If he wishes to count negative divisors as well, simply multiply the result by two as the positive and negative divisors are in one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: @JMoravitz can you please elaborate for negative divisors ?

Comment: @JonGarrick What is there to elaborate?  If $k\mid n$ then $-k\mid n$ and vice versa.  E.g. the positive divisors of $6$ are $6,3,2,1$ but if you include negative divisors you have $6,3,2,1,-1,-2,-3,-6$.  The question is whether you are talking *specifically* divisibility of natural numbers or if you are talking about divisibility of integers.